# strategy game help: fog of war

Tags: java, algorithm

im trying to make a real time strategy game such as starcraft or age of empires. my maps woud have to support up to about 1500 entities. My problem arrises with how to implement a fog of war without lagging the game. The method that i initialy tried was to simply caclulate the distance to all surrounding area of a unit everytime it moved but as i expected this lagged since many units would be constantly moving. If anyone knows a faster algorythim for a fog of war please help. the maps would be tile based and stored in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quite basic implementation can be as follows:

- Visibility is given by a value `v[i,j]` for each tile `(i,j)`. Any value below a certain threshold lies within the fog.
- The values are updated with regular time steps (note: for such a thing no high accuracy or high frequency is needed besides for very special cases) using the following two steps:

  1. blur the current map `v[i,j]`
  2. for each `unit` increase the value `v[unit_i, unit_j]` by a constant amount. You can also add a constant amount *if* a unit is on a square (no matter how many of them are there).

Comment: im not following exactly. i understand your basic consept and i think ill end up using that but what do you mean by bluring the map and what is unit_i and unit_j supposed to be?

Comment: @stas a blur is more or less a filter applied to your array (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur). You might have seen it with images where the image is smeared out. With unit_i and unit_j I just wanted to describe the map-tile a unit is actually standing on.

Comment: why would i want to blur it though?

Comment: @stas In order to have some radius where the units influence visibility. E.g. in a one-dimensional case the unit will set the map to `[0,0,0,1,0,0,0]` which after one step looks e.g. like `[0,0,0.25,1,0.25,0,0]`. Thus, depending on the threshold you have either one visible map tile (where the unit is) or three. Blurring is an easy way to "spread" the units across the map without actually calculating the distances.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution: binning for your entities.

You create a relatively spare grid, or even a quad-tree. Given coordinates `(x,y)`, it allows you to find in `log(d)` steps all entities which are in the same (or neighbouring) cells, where `d` is the depth of your quad-tree.

With some help of ropes (pointers from leaf nodes pointing to adjacent cells), accessing a neighbour can be done in a constant time.

To learn if a given map tile is visible or not, you just need a query into your quad-tree.

Also, a quad-tree may be useful for other tasks unrelated to fog-of-war. E.g. you might want to find the nearest "worker" to the given coordinates `(x,y)` or you want to apply some area-damage to all units in a region.

Comment: Still. Writing your own stuff (e.g. games) is a great opportunity to learn new stuff :) Just google or check out the wiki for a start. There is lots of programming stuff out there.

Answer (score 1):

Every time a unit moves, you can probably assume that it moves to neighboring tile, can't you? In this case you can also assume that visible area of this unit also moves by one tile in the same direction, so you should have no trouble determining nor updating an area that is supposed to be visible. Depending on sight radius of a unit, updating only values that need updating can probably save a lot of CPU power.

The problem would be area that is supposed to be blurred - there can be more units seeing the same tile but this can be solved by doing what Howard suggests.

Comment: that might work however then i would have to store the previous point every unit since they do not move by tiles but the tiles are like map peices and they can move within and between them.

Comment: It depends really on how big the tiles are. Can you update FOW only when unit moves to another tile and not within a tile? If not, then what I wrote here won't help you much.